# How to ellipsize the text in the last element of a flex-box row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vuejs3

I have a structure in my Vue3 app where we show contact information.  First, we show a briefcase icon and the company name (if there is one), and then we show a sillhouette icon an the contact's name.  These are displayed in a row, and if the total text is too long, I want to ellipsize just the last element in the row, the contact's name.  One wrinkle to this is that the user can search for contacts with either company or contact name, and we want to highlight the matching text.  This is achieved by using v-html to add a  around the matching text.  This is the HTML structure I have while testing (before adding the v-html):

```
<div class="contacts-section">
  <div class="contact">
    <forge-icon :image-name="'BriefcaseDark'" class="partner-icon" />
    <div class="partner-text">
      Test Partner
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact">
    <forge-icon :image-name="'ProfileDarkSmall'" class="contact-icon" />
    <div class="location-text">
      Testifer L. Contactson III Blah Blah Blah
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS I have for this section:

```
.contacts-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  @include text(0.875rem);
}
.contact {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  .partner-text {
    margin-right: 16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .location-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}
.partner-icon,
.contact-icon {
  margin-right: 4px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

So far this all looks exactly how I want, except that the contact name refuses to ellipsize, it just ignores the `overflow: hidden` rule and extends past the edge of the frame:
[image]

If anyone has any advice on how to get the `text-overflow` to actually work, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

It took a little bit of tweaking, but I got this working.  The key was adding `min-width: 0` to the outermost overflowing div:

```
.contacts-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  @include text(0.875rem);
}
.contact {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 0;
  .partner-text {
    margin-right: 16px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .location-text {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
}
.partner-icon,
.contact-icon {
  margin-right: 4px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

There may be some more rules I can clean up, but this is working correctly.